# Get correct tf from robot_state_publisher

Tags: robot-state-publisher, transform-listener, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Question:** How do I get the correct tf from robot_state_publisher?

**Details and background:**
I have a urdf file (snippet shown below) describing a joint:

```
<joint name="scan_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="base_scan"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.172" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="base_scan">
```

and a launch file that launches a `robot_state_publisher` node. Here's the snippet.

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
  <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
</node>
```

After launching the file, everything looks good when I validate the tf by `rostopic echo /tf_static`. Here's the relevant part of the terminal output:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 3
    nsecs: 722000000
  frame_id: "robot_1/base_link"
child_frame_id: "robot_1/base_scan"
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -0.032
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.172
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

But when I use `rosrun tf_echo robot_1/base_link robot_1/base_scan`, the tf changed even though it's static. You see after the 2nd iteration onwards, the tf changed from `[-0.032, 0.000, 0.172]` to `[-0.064, 0.000, 0.122]`.

```
At time 0.000
- Translation: [-0.032, 0.000, 0.172]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 0.000
- Translation: [-0.032, 0.000, 0.172]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 0.000
- Translation: [-0.064, 0.000, 0.122]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 0.000
- Translation: [-0.064, 0.000, 0.122]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

I also tried using python TransformListener, and the result was the same. The tf changed after some time. There's no other node broadcasting this tf besides robot_state_publisher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395113/get-correct-tf-from-robot_state_publisher/) by [didi1311](https://answers.ros.org/users/52228/didi1311/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok found the problem.

Turned out I have this line left uncommented in another launchfile that also broadcasts the same tf.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="-0.064 0 0.122 0 0 0 robot_$(arg robot_id)/base_link robot_$(arg robot_id)/base_scan 100" />
```

Turned this node off and it works. My bad

---

Originally posted by [didi1311](https://answers.ros.org/users/52228/didi1311/) with karma: 18 on 2022-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0